# Stopping debugger at an optimized out line of code

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

If I want to stop in an empty block of code it's always a problem.

```
if (...)
{ // I want the debugger to stop here!
}
```

If I add an arbitrary line of code which does not affect program behaviour it is likely to be optimized out, depending on the line

```
if (...)
{ 
   int a;
   a = a; // won't work
}
if (...)
{ 
   int a;
   int b = a; // will work
}
```

So the 2 questions arise here:

1) What is the simplest one-line code which will NOT be optimized out (but will really do nothing!), which I can use to stop the debugger?
2) Is there a way to switch all of optimizations so that to be able to stop at an *arbitrary* line of code? Compiler flag -O0 doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good enough one-line code could be some useful and interesting `assert` statement with a condition which would not be constant-folded by the compiler. Often some meaningful and useful `assert (p!=NULL)` or`assert(i>0)` where `p` is some existing pointer variable or formal, or `i` is some existing signed integer variable or formal, is enough.

BTW, you are in the debugging phase of your project, so adding good enough meaningful `assert` statements is helpful. Of course you want the [`<cassert>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/) header to be included.

Don't forget that [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html) statements are skipped if you compile with the `-DNDEBUG` flag.

You could also use (on Linux/x86) `asm volatile ("nop")`. Notice that the debugger needs some code to put a breakpoint at. You don't want an *empty* code.

Comment: This will help, but this is more than one line of code, counting the variable declaration.

Comment: No, you should add meaningful asserts. You won't declare any new variable, you would use some existing variable instead. So that is a single line.

Comment: asm volatile ("nop") works fine and it doesn't require additional includes

Comment: But `asm volatile ("nop")`  is probably not portable. Some processor or assembler may have a no-op instruction which is not spelt `nop`; and some C compilers might not accept it.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a [static breakpoint](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/AddingUserSpaceProbingToApps)?

```
#include <sys/sdt.h>

if (condition)
  DTRACE_PROBE(myapp, foo);
```

Now you can set a [breakpoint](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints.html) in GDB:

```
break -probe-stap myapp:foo
```

You can even use:

```
DTRACE_PROBE1(myapp, foo, condition);
```

with:

```
break -probe-stap myapp:foo if $_probe_arg0
```

Comment: What is 'break -probe-stap myapp:foo if $_probe_arg0', is this a command to be run under pure GDB? I would be nice to have a way of doing this compatibly with IDE like QtCreator.

Comment: @VladimirLenin: yes, this is using GDB directly. This feature might not be available in GUIs. You be able to put the step manually in with the GUI on the line.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work. Works, if even just added DTRACE_PROBE1(myapp, foo, condition);, without break directive. For what the latter is, then?